# Match certain part of URI

Tags: java

I need to parse into a variable a certain part of a URI for a Spring filter I am writing.  I am trying to extract out a username, which could be the last part of the URI, part of a more complex URI or contain query string parameters after the username.

**Example inputs**

- /users/jay
- /users/jay/profile
- /users/jay?var=value

In each case I would like to end up with a string containing "jay".  Would simply using `indexOf` be appropriate here, or is this better suited to a regex?  I have limited experience with regular expressions in Java so any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You could always split on `"[/\\?]"` and then capture the String after "users".

Comment: Or perhaps capture with `"/users/(\\w+)"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this properly I suggest you use the [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class.

```
URI users = URI.create("/users"); // Can be put as a final static field

URI uri = URI.create(uriString);  // Can be skipped if you have a URI as input

String afterUsers = users.relativize(uri).getPath();
if (afterUsers.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("No user");
else
    System.out.println("User: " + afterUsers.split("/", 2)[0]);
```